# I ate out last Monday. or I ate out on Monday

Tags: grammaticality

Can someone tell me which is correct. **I ate out last Monday.  or I ate out on Monday.** When I am talking about last Monday- February 12 and today is 18th.

Comment: Why do you think something is incorrect??

Comment: @tchrist Oh I am not really sure if it is incorrect but I don't know which has a proper usage.

Answer (score 2):

If one says "I ate out on Monday" it necessarily implies the nearest previous Monday.

"Last Monday" generally implies "Monday of last week".  For example, if today were Tuesday or Wednesday and someone said "I ate out last Monday", almost no one would wonder if they meant yesterday. But as days pass, particularly towards the end of the week and especially on the weekend, that difference becomes more muddled.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I now understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

So I'd say if a Monday had past since you ate out, then I suppose you would say "I Ate Out Last Monday."
If, say its the next day, so Tuesday. "I ate out on Monday," Would be what you want to say.